# Create a rent product

Tags: commerce

I'm using the Drupal Commerce module to build a Website to manage two Flats **to be rented by days**.

The visitor select one of the two flats and then select a date (let's say it the day: 15 January 2012) and make the payment for it.

After the payment the date of 15 January 2012 will not be available to be sold again until this day has passed (the 16 january).

I first thought of creating a product type called: **Day to rent** with a field called: **date** and then creating 365 'Day to rent' products, each one for each one of the days of the year, setting the field 'date' to the corresponding date.

Then, using the calendar module and views I would show the products in the calendar allowing the visitor to click in the 'add to cart' for the day they choose.

I'm a Newbie with the module, and I now see that I cannot get 'products' inside a view. Then, my idea fails.

Now I think that I should add the field called: date to the 'Product display' instead of the product itself, but I am not sure.

Before wasting hours, I just need to know if is there any way I can accomplish this with the commerce module.
Do I need an affiliated module? Do I need to develop a new module?
What is the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal [Rooms](http://drupal.org/project/rooms) module is a perfect solution to this. It is a booking and room management solution for hotels, vacation rentals and B&Bs. It integrates directly with Drupal 7 Commerce.